# Boot ubuntu 16.04 in text mode without 'X'

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04, xorg

Context : I upgrade to 16.04 and it breaks my Radeon driver. I uninstall xserver and reinstall it with standard driver. But I uninstall also **xserver-xorg-input-all** so I can't login and after some time it's freeze.
If xserver launch I get none input (mouse, keyboard).

So I try to boot in console mode editing grub launch script typing 'e' in grub and replace `quiet splash` by `text` but finally graphical login screen come up.

Comment: I see some answer but I have no access to modify systemd and grub modification is not enough to boot without X in 16.04

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default display manager, `sudo systemctl mask lightdm.service` should do it.

You can also edit the procline to include `init=/bin/bash`, but that will seriously mess up your boot (i.e. pretty much nothing will start except for the core components of your linux kernel)

If you are having problems booting, you can always stick it into another computer, and then `cd $DODGY_DISK; sudo chroot .`, and see what you can do from there.

Comment: I suggest disabling service instead of deleteion.

Comment: Ok, I have adjusted my answer @yurii